# Compare varchar date value in SQL Server 2014 not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a vendor DB where I am trying to COMPARE the date VARCHAR values stored in their DB via a CASE statement in my UPDATE statement but I'm having problems converting the HHS.StatusEfffectiveDate if in fact the value is less than 10/02/2017 as stated in my code below.  Any help/direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

My date column (HHS.StatusEffectiveDate) is defined as a varchar(10).  Here is my sql code:

```
UPDATE HHS 
SET HHS.StatusEffectiveDate = 
    (
    CASE
        WHEN CAST(HHS.StatusEffectiveDate AS DATE) <= '10/02/2017' THEN '10/05/2017'
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(SVEY.Effective_Date AS DATE),101)
    END
    ),
    HHS.Enddate = SVEY.End_Date

FROM Mcsfwisdtest.FRA.dbo.vw_HHSurvey SVEY
INNER JOIN dbo.Focus_Export_Econ_DisadvantagedHHS HHS
ON HHS.StudentID = SVEY.CustomerID
```

CORRECTION to CASE statement:

```
CASE
    WHEN CAST(SVEY.Effective_Date AS DATE) <= '2017-10-02' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '10/05/2017', 101)
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(SVEY.Effective_Date AS DATE),101)
END
```

Comment: Please elucidate - are you getting incorrect values, error messages, or ??. Also, sample data that shows both correct and incorrect results would help as well.

Comment: My apologies.  I have a value in the HHS .StatusEffectiveDate that is '09/12/2017' which is LESSER than '10/02/2017'.  Consequently I want to UPDATE the HHS.StatusEffectiveDate with '10/05/2017' which is NOT working.

Comment: For starters you should use the ANSI string format for dates. YYYYMMDD What you have there for string literals can fail depending on your settings. Is it possible to change the table so that you can store dates as dates instead of strings?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the table definition for this column.

Comment: Is that row filtered out based on your join? Without some actual details here we are shooting in the dark. Provide the table structure and sample data that will replicate the issue.

Comment: It might be that your database does not understands '10/02/2017'. Always use language neutral formats for data values. See this http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp#DtFormatsInput

Comment: Why not just convert first and then update?

Comment: I think @GuidoG has a good point. Melinda, can you explicitly try telling sql what `'10/02/2017'` is? ie...  `convert(date, '10/02/2017', 110)`

Comment: If you are stuck with holding dates in char() format, then IMHO it is better use the ISO date format YYYY-MM-DD, with dashes, particularly for date literal values as this is easier for the human reader. It also means you do not need to convert CHAR to DATE in order to compare dates or when sorting on column values. Unless, that is, you actually need to know the period between dates.

Comment: @JohnRC I agree with using an ISO format, but I believe that YYYY-MM-DD is not an iso format. YYYYMMDD is. See here http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp#DtFormatsInput

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input.  Your time and help are appreciated.  The resolution to my issues were 2-fold.  The syntax in my CASE statement was incorrect and the referenced table/columns and logic in the WHERE clause were incorrect.  Once these issues were resolved VIOLA the issue was resolved.  Thank you again to everyone.

Comment: @GuidoG Hmmm.. I don't want to be picky and either approach is better than not, but I thought ISO 8601 specifically includes dashes [ISO 8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html).

Comment: @JohnRC Yes you are right about it being ISO. But I thought that this ISO format is not language neutral. My bad